# How to convert scrape list using BeautifulSoup into dataframe?

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I am scraping data from this website: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M. using BeautifulSoup and have to show it in a table format with three columns: Postcode, Borough, Neighbour. I want to convert the scrape list from a list to a dataframe so that I can delete some rows and do further manipulation on the dataframe.

Get the following error message:

[image: error message]

Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd 

import numpy as np

import requests

from tabulate import tabulate

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M")

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content,'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())

table = soup.find_all('table')[0]

df = pd.read_html(str(table))

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_items(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save yourself quite a bit of time and effort by using pandas built-in `read_html` directly on the page

```
df=pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M')[0]

df.head()

    0       1       2
0   Postcode    Borough Neighbourhood
1   M1A Not assigned    Not assigned
2   M2A Not assigned    Not assigned
3   M3A North York  Parkwoods
4   M4A North York  Victoria Village
```

Note that, on its own, `read_html` returns a list of all tables found on the page as dataframes, hence indexing to get the element at `[0]` for our dataframe.

I leave it to you to tweak as needed to fix the column headings